# Extracting data from a web page using VBA code

Tags: vba

I am wrting a visual basic code to automatically extract some weather data. The following is the source code of the web page.

```
<tr><td>
<table align="center" width="100%" summary="table used for formatting"><tr>
<td align="center"><b>Example:</b></td>
<td align="center" width="40%">Latitude 33.5<br>Longitude -80.75</td>
<td align="center">OR</td>
<td align="center" width="40%">Latitude 33 30<br>Longitude -80 45</td>
</tr></table></td></tr>
<tr><td><table width="100%" summary="table used for formatting"><tr>
<td><b><label for="lat">Latitude? </label>
<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" size="12" value=""></b></td>
<td width="30%">South:&nbsp;&nbsp; -90 to 0</td>
<td width="30%">North:&nbsp;&nbsp; 0 to 90</td>
</tr><tr>
<td><b><label for="lon">Longitude? </label>
<input type="text" name="lon" id="lon" size="12" value=""></b></td>
<td width="30%">West:&nbsp;&nbsp; -180 to 0</td>
<td width="30%">East:&nbsp;&nbsp; 0 to 180</td>
</tr></table></td></tr>
<tr><td><table align="center" summary="table used for formatting"><tr>
<td><b> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </b></td>
<td><b> <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Reset "> </b></td>
<td><i> This form is "Reset" if the input is out of range. </i></td>
</tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
</form>
```

I am getting an error (Object variable or With block variable not set). Could anybody help me on this code? Thank you very much in advance. Here is what I have written:

```
Sub extractSolData()
Dim IE As Object
Dim latitude As String, longitude As String


Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

latitude = InputBox("Enter Latitude of the location")
longitude = InputBox("Enter Longitude of the location")

With IE
.Visible = True
.navigate ("https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?email=skip@larc.nasa.gov")

While IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

IE.document.getElementsByName(“lat”).Item(0).Value = latitude
IE.document.getElementsByName(“lon”).Item.innertext = longitude


IE.document.getElementsByName("submit").Item.Value = "Submit"

Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
End With

Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to indicate *exactly where* you're getting the error.  `getElementsByName` always returns a collection (even when there's only a single match in the document) so whenever you use it you need to address a single element in that collection.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the tip!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the quotation marks you are using in

```
IE.document.getElementsByName(“lat”).Item(0).Value = latitude
IE.document.getElementsByName(“lon”).Item.innertext = longitude
```

These are not real quotes, I bet you copied this from a website and somehow the quotations marks got messed up. They need to look like

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("lat").Item(0).Value = latitude
IE.document.getElementsByName("lon").Item.innertext = longitude
```

Comment: Hi Jeanno! Thanks for the catch brother!! It worked. Frankly I don't remember copying them from any website but I used an earlier code from a Notepad file. Perhaps these came from there. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 1):

You could have shortened all of that to the following by concatenating the lat on long into URL string:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub nota_ong()
    Dim latitude As String, longitude As String

    latitude = InputBox("Enter Latitude of the location")
    longitude = InputBox("Enter Longitude of the location")

    If latitude = vbNullString Or longitude = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/grid.cgi?email=skip%40larc.nasa.gov&step=1&lat=" & LATITUDE & "&lon=" & LONGITUDE & "&submit=Submit"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'Do stuff with new page
        'Quit '< Uncomment this later
    End With
End Sub
```