# Extract data from a web page that may not be formatted as a table

Tags: html, vba, excel

For starters I am by no means an expert in VBA.  Just know enough to be dangerous 8).

I started out by doing a search on how to extract a table from a web page and saw many many people have asked the same question.  Unfortunately most of what I was reading was over my head. One article I read pointed me to this [detailed article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards/8846791#8846791) by Siddharth Rout, but alas I could not follow what was going on other than there are two methods internet explorer or some other methods.  Since I only have IE11 installed and MS Office I would prefer to go the IE route.

I have encountered this problem several times in the past and have always dropped the project or done things manually.  Today I thought I would try and learn how to do this and make my future life hopefully a little easier.  As such I am going to use data from a gaming website since it mimics other things I have encountered in the past.

So today's (this week's..no this month's..I am an optimist!) project is to build a list of every team involved in a tournament and copy their results into excel.  This would be akin to pulling cricket, hockey, baseball, soccer, or football stats.  I tried using Excel's built in Get Data From Web process, but it did not identify the table on the web page.

The address for the web page is: http://worldoftanks.com/en/tournaments/1000000017/

and is in the image below

[image: Web Page Example]

So the basics and my starting point is to simply pull the list of teams from 1 group and paste it in an excel page with no formatting.  Basically the area in yellow in the image above.  The image could not fit the whole page but there are actually 10 teams in this group.  However I would like to make it variable as sometimes you may have more or less than 10 teams in a group. I am going to assume the number of rows is a minor issue at this point.

Once I get that part figured out I am hoping it will be relatively easy to switch to the next group, grab that list of teams and results and add them to the end of the list I am building in excel.  On the web page this would be done by selecting the blue areas.

Now once I have those two things figured out I would need to build the list again from scratch based on the stage of the tournament areas in green and put that list on a new page.  I have some ideas how to achieve this but it will really depend on what the previous two steps look like.

I have a bonus task for myself too which is to pull the schedule for each team in a group to see how they did against various other teams.  Who beat who type deal.  I am hoping I can figure that part out based on the information learned from the task above.

So I am pretty sure there are other languages/prgs that are better suited for the task at hand, but I would like to stick with what I have...and the little I know so far.  So I tried a wee bit of VBA code and commented on what I need to achieve.  So far I think I have opened the webpage! and built a bit a thought process in comments on how to do some of the things.

```
Sub GetTeamData()
Dim IE As Object
Dim roundcounter As Integer
Dim groupcounter As Integer
Dim TeamList As Variant
Dim WebAddress As String
Dim Number_of_rounds as Integer
Dim Number_of_Groups as Integer

'set webaddress of site to link to
WebAddress = "http://worldoftanks.com/en/tournaments/1000000017/"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate (WebAddress)
End With

'What does this chunk of code do?  Wait for webpage to finish loading?
While IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

'set initial parameters for loops.  I am ok with hardcoding this for now.
Number_of_groups = 125
Number_of_rounds = 5

'start pulling teamdata

'For roundcounter = 1 To number_of_rounds
    'select roundcounter on webpage
    'for groupcounter = 1 to number_of_groups
        'select groupcounter on webpage
        'grab table of 6-10 teams (position, team name, battles, wins, losses, ties, and points)
        'add table to TeamList
    'next groupcounter
    'paste TeamList to sheet roundcounter cell A1
    'clear TeamList
'next roundcounter


'Next task
'based on results on how to pull group table date, pull individual team schedule results to build matrix result

Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

One thing I was thinking about was that instead of using for next loops with a counter is if it would be easier to set it up to do a loop until an error had occurred like exceeding the number of groups or rounds.  Now I am rambling.

Anyhow if someone would be so kind to **get me started on how to pull the yellow area from the image above** that would be much appreciated!  Please be gentle!  I do realize that this question has been asked many a time... I just did not understand what I was reading.  Also if this is not possible or extremely difficult to do please let me know.  Thank you in advance for your assistance in educating me.

## UPDATE 16/03/19 0900

So I tried the Get Data From Web process again this morning with a bit more luck...but not much.

[image: Get From Web]

after 1 error window which I click yes to I get the web page to load

[image: error window on load]

I got the little yellow arrow to show up once on the page in the very top left corner.  So I tried it and it did pull in information.

[image: Get From Web tick box]

but I did notice there were no yellow boxes next to the table I want which makes me wonder if it is not a table.

[image]

When I did pull in information, it was not the information I was looking for. When I scanned through the results, I could see where the data I am looking for should be, but all the results are missing, just the table column headers show up in about Row 263 or so.

[image: web querry results]

So then I tried doing a copy and paste method from the web page using select all for the copy on the web page.  For the paste I tried different methods.  keeping source formatting resulted in nothing.  keep destination formatting brought in information.  I tried paste special (html, Unicode and text)  HTML made things look pretty and the other two put everything into a single column.  More importantly the results were in the table.

[image: copy paste results]

Now if I only needed round 1 group 1 team list and results I could work with this.  Simply delete all the rows above and below the table and voila!  however since the web address is the same for every group and every round I have no idea how to "click" on the blue or green areas to update the info.  If I knew this I could automate the process by copying and pasting each page, then editing the results to just the table, and moving the table to another sheet just below the last results.

To me there seems like there should be a better method.

### 16/03/19 1600

```html
<!-- ko if: visibleBracketType() === ROUND_ROBIN -->
<table class="tournament-table tournament-table__indent" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr class="tournament-table_tr">
    <th class="tournament-table_th tournament-table_th__numb">#</th>
    <th class="tournament-table_th">
      <div class="tournament-table_ico-holder">
        <span class="ico-team">Team</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tournament-table_heading-text">
        Team
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="tournament-table_th">
      <div class="tournament-table_ico-holder">
        <span class="ico-battles">Battles</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tournament-table_heading-text">
        Battles
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="tournament-table_th">
      <div class="tournament-table_ico-holder">
        <span class="ico-victory">Victories</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tournament-table_heading-text">
        Victories
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="tournament-table_th tournament-table_th__mobile-hide">
      <div class="tournament-table_ico-holder">
        <span class="ico-flag">Defeats</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tournament-table_heading-text">
        Defeats
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="tournament-table_th tournament-table_th__mobile-hide">
      <div class="tournament-table_ico-holder">
        <span class="ico-division">Draws</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tournament-table_heading-text">
        Draws
      </div>
    </th>
    <th class="tournament-table_th">
      <div class="tournament-table_ico-holder">
        <span class="ico-points">Points</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tournament-table_heading-text">
        Points
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko foreach: {data: rrBrackets().teams, as: 'team' } -->
  <tr class="tournament-table_tr" data-bind="css: {'tournament-table_tr__my-team': team.team_id === $root.currentUserTeamIdInCurrentGroup()}">
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.position"></td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="css: {'tournament-table_td__my-team': team.team_id === $root.currentUserTeamIdInCurrentGroup()}">
      <a class="tournament-table_team tournament-table_team__big" target="_blank" data-bind="text: team.team_title, attr: {href: $root.getTournamentTeamUrl(team.team_id)}"></a>
    </td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.battle_played"></td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.wins"></td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td tournament-table_td__mobile-hide" data-bind="text: team.losses"></td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td tournament-table_td__mobile-hide" data-bind="text: team.draws"></td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.extra_statistics.points"></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
</table>​
```

ok, from what I am gathering from the various posts I have been reading and videos I have been watching, I need to find some critical "Tag" in the coding of the web page and from that I can eventually start pulling data.  I hit F12 on IE to view the code, and then in the code area I did a search on some of the display text in the area I was looking and found the above chunk of "code".  With a lot of GUESSING I am hoping I grabbed the right chunk.  Now to figure out what that critical tag is and how to use it.  By the way, what code is that web page in?

Comment: I also tried looking at the source code of the web page as per this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679080/extracting-data-from-a-web-page-using-vba-code), but I could not make heads or tails of the source code.

Comment: In the code snippet you included, it's still HTML: `<tr><\tr>` for table rows, `<th><\th>` for table headers and `<td><\td>` for table data/columns. The problem will be extracting the actual data because they're binded and you can only "read" the HTML source code. If actual data can be seen from "View Source" of the page, then you can read data using VBA.

Comment: Thank you Rowen.  That will help narrow down my searches for data scraping HTML pages with excel VBA 8).  Only a couple of thousand pages to wade through now!  Seriously though, thank you for that as I had only guessed at HTML when I put that tag on it.

Comment: So i am not sure, if i am understanding you correctly, but the one missing part is to click the right Buttons ?

Comment: no, the bold line part just below my code. is the Primary concern if I breakdown what I want to do.  That is pull the yellow area (numbers and names) from the first screen shot.  Once I can figure that part out with people help, the secondary part will be to do the click so to change the data display so I can repeat the data pull of the yellow area.  No point in doing the click if I cant pull the data.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: As you progress you may be interested in the APIs: https://developers.wargaming.net/reference/all/wotb/tournaments/tables/?language=en&r_realm=eu&run=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if written a small Sub which i think should solve your Problem if i understood you correctly. Of course you will invest some work, since it only reads one stage right now. But it reads the data from every Group:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'make sure you add references to Microsoft Internet Controls (shdocvw.dll) and
 'Microsoft HTML object Library.
 'Code will NOT run otherwise.

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls (shdocvw.dll)
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Dim htmlCurrentDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim RowNumber As Integer
            RowNumber = 1

With objIE
    .Navigate "http://worldoftanks.com/en/tournaments/1000000017/" ' Main page
    .Visible = 0
    Do While .READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))


        Set htmlDoc = .document

        Dim ButtonRoundData As Variant
        Set ButtonRoundData = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("group-stage_link")

        Dim ButtonData As Variant
        Set ButtonData = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("groups_link")



        Dim button As HTMLLinkElement
        For Each button In ButtonData

           Debug.Print button.nodeName

            button.Click

               Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) ' This is to prevent double entryies but it is not clean. you should definitly check if the table is still the same and wait then

            Set htmlCurrentDoc = .document
            Dim RawData As HTMLTable
            Set RawData = htmlCurrentDoc.getElementsByClassName("tournament-table tournament-table__indent")(0)



            Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
            ColumnNumber = 1

            Dim hRow As HTMLTableRow
            Dim hCell As HTMLTableCell
            For Each hRow In RawData.Rows

                For Each hCell In hRow.Cells
                    Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber).Value = hCell.innerText
                    ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1
                Next hCell
                ColumnNumber = 1
                RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
            Next hRow

            RowNumber = RowNumber + 3
        Next button
    End With

End Sub
```

What it does is starting an invisible IE, reads the data, clicks the button, reads the next and so on ...

for Debugging i suggest to set .Visible to 1, so you will se what happens.

**EDIT 1:** if you get a debbuging error, try to Abort and run it again, it definitly Needs some error handling, if the Website isn't loaded right.

**EDIT 2:** Made it a bit stabler, you should really pay Attention, since the Webpage takes some time to load, you MUST check if the data has changed before writting it. if it hasn't changed wait a second or so and then try again.

Here some sample data i got in Excel:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Let me read through it and test it out.  If it can pull the yellow area WOOT!  that is 90% of my battle.  I figure if I can learn how you did the click for groups then I should easily repeat that process for the Stages.

Comment: yes you should be able to do that, it is actually not that difficult code, i will update my data with a debug.print log

Comment: so I was reading your code, and did not get very far when i saw you added in the comments that I needed to add some libraries.  [I posted this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117694/vba-userform-toolbox-additional-controls-dialogue-window-not-showing) shortly after I started on this project and I am wondering if its going to be a problem.

Comment: I think I can definitely work with what you are showing. as results.  Kind of ugly looking, but it would spoil all my fun learning this task if you did it all for me! 8)  Still reading the code and figuring out the adding of libraries issue.  And that is definitely a separate issue.

Comment: ooh cheesus i hope not, additional librarys can be selected on the top menu. Extras->References i think in english if this doesnt works try activating the allow Access to vba-projectmodell in the trust center

Comment: yeah of course i just looped the table and debug.print ever cell by it's one, to fill it nicely in to a table is your Job ;)

Comment: I got the two libraries added.  They showed up in the list for reference libraries.  Just stepping through trying to figure out what is happening.  see how it compares at what I was thinking of in my original bit of code layout.  Definitely a lot shorter than I thought it would be.  But that is what happens when you know what you are doing 8).

Comment: in your code, you have a comment section `'set user name and password`  and one line of code underneath it.  I am not following what is happening in that one line of code.   I can see where passing a username and password would be helpful in certain situation so you have me curious.  I do realize that to pull the information from this page I do not need it though.  Could you explain that part of your code if something is happening there?

Comment: Aah ignore that, it's a leftover for a Passwort submit vba ;) you do not Need a Password to get that data

Comment: Ok, you had my mind racing and at this hour not a good thing.  I turned visibility on as I was not sure anything was happening.  I then saw it flipping through groups (after second loop) and it eventually got to the debug.print line.  Where is that debug print information supposed to display?  I was envisioning a pop up window but nothing happened.  Is there a file I am supposed to open?  or am I having other issues with my comp?

Comment: press Ctrl + G that opens the direct window

Comment: This is perfect answer for what I was looking for.  You may be spoon feeding me tid bits but that is exactly what I wanted.  Something to get me started and i could chew on and figure stuff out with.  Formatting I can take care of and with what you have supplied I should be able to figure out how to loop through the stages!  I salute you!

Comment: Liking the update, and I understand what you are saying about the waiting for it to load.

Comment: You know how you added the reatime pause after coding the button click, would the .readystate<>4 bit of code work here too?

Comment: good thinking but unfortunaly no. Since the data is loaded with some ("I think") js-libs. it won't work

Comment: when this bounty is up I will start another bounty and award it to you.  I think the two f you both deserve it, but I can only give out one bounty at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Although extracting data from a webpage can be automated with VBA (see below), the specific example webpage you provided comes with some obstacles:

This webpage loads and displays only a small portion of the desired data at a time. This is probably done for performance reasons, since the whole table of Teams would consist of several thousand entries.
Only the Teams of the currently displayed Round and currently displayed Group are loaded.
If you click on another Group, a JavaScript program (running in your browser) is started that connects to the server, fetches the Teams of that Group and replaces the data in the webpage. You can verify this by yourself if you press F12 and observe the Network tab that lists all requests to the server.

Thus, the webpage does not provide at any point a complete list of Teams. You would have to work around this:

1. Make your program automatically click on each Round, then click on each Group and finally extract the 9 teams of that Group, merging everything together afterwards.
2. Hook into the JavaScript code that loads each Group's Teams and call it in a loop, or reverse-engineer the requests made by that code and try to re-create them in VBA. Although this could be an elegant solution, many website owners do not like having their API used in ways they did not intend.
   A misuse could create a huge server load. I would only recommend this method if the API was designed for this purpose (some websites do this, like Twitter or Steam).

---

The following will focus on just extracting content from a given page, that is, retrieving the Teams of the currently loaded Group. I won't use any of the workarounds mentioned above.

The program basically consists of these three parts:

### Open Webpage

The following is a helper function that opens a webpage and returns an object with the webpage's content.
It needs the libraries *Microsoft Internet Controls* and *Microsoft HTML Object Library* referenced ([see here for instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx)).

```
' return the document containg the DOM of the page strWebAddress
' returns Nothing if the timeout lngTimeoutInSeconds was reached
Public Function GetIEDocument(ByVal strWebAddress As String, Optional ByVal lngTimeoutInSeconds As Long = 15) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim IEDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim dateNow As Date

    ' create an IE application, representing a tab
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    ' optionally make the application visible, though it will work perfectly fine in the background otherwise
    IE.Visible = True

    ' open a webpage in the tab represented by IE and wait until the main request successfully finished
    ' times out after lngTimeoutInSeconds with a warning
    IE.Navigate strWebAddress
    dateNow = Now
    Do While IE.Busy
        If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Function
    Loop

    ' retrieve the webpage's content (that is, the HTML DOM) and wait until everything is loaded (images, etc.)
    ' times out after lngTimeoutInSeconds with a warning
    Set IEDocument = IE.Document
    dateNow = Now
    Do While IEDocument.ReadyState <> "complete"
        If Now > DateAdd("s", lngTimeoutInSeconds, dateNow) Then Exit Function
    Loop

    Set GetIEDocument = IEDocument
End Function
```

### Extract Information

You can now load the webpage by using `Set IEDocument = GetIEDocument("http://worldoftanks.com/en/tournaments/1000000017/")`. The object `IEDocument` then contains everything you need to extract the desired data.

First you need to find the part that you want to extract (the *critical "Tag"*, as you called it).
Since the content of a webpage is represented as a tree of HTML tags, you need to find the table tag that contains all other tags that you are interested in. You already spotted it in your *16/03/19 1600* update. The `<table>` tag contains two `<tr>` tags (**t**able **r**ow), the first being the header row filled with `<th>` tags (**t**able **h**eader) representing the header of a single column.
The second row is a dummy row representing the entry of one Team.

The prepending line `<!-- ko foreach: {data: rrBrackets().teams, as: 'team' } -->` is part of the [Knockout Framwork](http://knockoutjs.com/), a JavaScript library employed by the website to dynamically fill the bare HTML tags with content. This is the reason why there is only one row in the HTML source, but in the rendered page you see nine rows: After the page is loaded, the JavaScript code loops over the list of Teams and creates a new row for each, populated with their respective data.

This, however, does not need to concern us: `IEDocument` contains the final version of the HTML DOM, after all loading was done (also see edit at the bottom). The first row looks actually like this (press F12 and have a look at the DOM Explorer tab for yourself):

```html
<tr class="tournament-table_tr" data-bind="css: {'tournament-table_tr__my-team': team.team_id === $root.currentUserTeamIdInCurrentGroup()}">
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.position">1</td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="css: {'tournament-table_td__my-team': team.team_id === $root.currentUserTeamIdInCurrentGroup()}">
        <a class="tournament-table_team tournament-table_team__big" href="/en/tournaments/1000000017/team/1000006728/" target="_blank" data-bind="text: team.team_title, attr: {href: $root.getTournamentTeamUrl(team.team_id)}">Pubbies</a>
    </td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.battle_played">8</td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.wins">7</td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td tournament-table_td__mobile-hide" data-bind="text: team.losses">1</td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td tournament-table_td__mobile-hide" data-bind="text: team.draws">0</td>
    <td class="tournament-table_td" data-bind="text: team.extra_statistics.points">21</td>
</tr>
```

Programmatically finding the  tag in the first place is, however, a bit more complicated. Usually structurally important tags have an `id` attribute that is unique. In such a case we could simply find it by using `IEDocument.getElementById("id_of_table_tag")`.
In this case our best bet is probably searching for the heading *Tournament brackets*:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="tournament-heading">Tournament brackets</h2>
</div>
```

If you inspect the following tree of HTML tags, to get to our `<table>` tag we need to go one step up in the hierarchy, skip the next two tags and from there on, use the first child tag for the next two tags:

```
' retrieve anchor element
For Each objH2 In IEDocument.getElementsByTagName("h2")
    If objH2.innerText = "Tournament brackets" Then Exit For
Next objH2

' traverse HTML tree to desired table element
' * move up one element in the hierarchy
' * skip two elements to proceed to the third (interjected each time with whitespace that is interpreted as an element of its own)
' * move down two elements n the hierarchy
' this may fail if the JavaScript code has not already populated the table
Set objTable = objH2.parentElement _
                    .nextSibling.nextSibling _
                    .nextSibling.nextSibling _
                    .nextSibling.nextSibling _
                    .children(0) _
                    .children(0)
```

As you can imagine, this is not very robust and is bound to break at any time if the layout of the webpage changes. There are other possible ways how to traverse the tree of HTML tags to finally reach the tag you seek.
See the [documentation of the Document object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods) for more.

All we need to do now is loop over the `Rows` of `objTable` and output each of its `Cells`.

### Output to Excel

As for the output, in this example, we keep it as simple as possible.
Put together with the above, the following code just outputs the table to the current worksheet in Excel:

```
Public Sub GetTeamData()
    Dim strWebAddress As String
    Dim strH2AnchorContent As String
    Dim IEDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim objH2 As MSHTML.HTMLHeaderElement
    Dim objTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    Dim objRow As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
    Dim objCell As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngColumn As Long

    ' initialize some variables that should probably better be passed as paramaters or defined as constants
    strWebAddress = "http://worldoftanks.com/en/tournaments/1000000017/"
    strH2AnchorContent = "Tournament brackets"

    ' open page
    Set IEDocument = GetIEDocument(strWebAddress)
    If IEDocument Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Timeout reached opening this address:" & vbNewLine & strWebAddress, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' retrieve anchor element
    For Each objH2 In IEDocument.getElementsByTagName("h2")
        If objH2.innerText = strH2AnchorContent Then Exit For
    Next objH2
    If objH2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find """ & strH2AnchorContent & """ in DOM!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' traverse HTML tree to desired table element
    ' * move up one element in the hierarchy
    ' * skip two elements to proceed to the third (interjected each time with whitespace that is interpreted as an element of its own)
    ' * move down two elements n the hierarchy
    Set objTable = objH2.parentElement _
                        .nextSibling.nextSibling _
                        .nextSibling.nextSibling _
                        .nextSibling.nextSibling _
                        .children(0) _
                        .children(0)

    ' iterate over the table and output its contents
    lngRow = 1
    For Each objRow In objTable.rows
        lngColumn = 1
        For Each objCell In objRow.cells
            Cells(lngRow, lngColumn) = objCell.innerText
            lngColumn = lngColumn + 1
        Next objCell
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Although this is only a partial solution for your current problem, this offers a general solution for how to programmatically extract data from a website using VBA.
As you said that you regularly encounter such problems, this might be of some use to you nonetheless.

---

### Edit

1. In his answer, Doktor OSwaldo rightfully declares the objects as exactly what they are - in contrast to my previous version where everything was of type `Object`. I didn't know of the *Microsoft HTML Object Library*. Thanks @Doktor OSwaldo. :)
   I incorporated the use of the library in my code above.
2. You should be aware that at the moment where `objTable` is set, the element might not yet exist in the DOM because of the JavaScript having not yet completely filled in all the data. You could put a loop around this statement checking if `objTable` was indeed successfully set:

   `On Error Resume Next
       Do
           Err.Clear
           Set objTable = ...
       Loop While Err
   On Error GoTo 0`

   You should probably include a timeout option as shown in function `GetIEDocument()`. All of this is best moved to a separate function that also clicks the Round and Group buttons as shown in Doktor OSwaldo's answer.
3. As you probably have already noticed, the header columns are output twice. This is actually correct because of the way the icon is shown before the header text.
   You can identify this with `objCell.tagName = "TH" And objCell.children.length = 2`, in which case you should use `objCell.children(1).innerText` instead of `objCell.innerText` to output to Excel.

Comment: I am still reading this.  You have done an excellent job of formatting and explaining why things are happening.

Comment: I do not think I would have ever got the Set objTable part of your code on my own.  Outputting to the spreadsheet I could do but the commands to grab the data beyond.  Interesting how you traverse the tree as you call it all in  single line.  This is definite building blocks for me.

Comment: really clean and good solution, but i think it will not be possible to click the Buttons without opening the page in IE